# Is it true that we can't use app link without internet connection?

Tags: android, android-intent, offline

So it seems like when I receive a google map shared location through sms as a hyperlink (which I suppose is an android app or deep link), I would not be able to open it directly with google maps without being connected to the internet. Anyone else finds this not normal?

Comment: try to open it with  offline maps app

Comment: like Maps.Me app

Comment: I think many phones' stock sms app would open a browser when you tap on the http link